# How to check multiple columns and add sum of 1 column in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame df

```
 emp = c("k","j","b","s","sy")
Exp = c(11,10,10,10,10)
Supv1 = c("d","k","j","k","an")
Supv2 = c("a","d","k","d", "a")

df <- data.frame(emp, Exp, Supv1, Supv2)

emp Exp Supv1 Sup2
 k    11  d     a
 j    10  k     d
 b    10  j     k
 s    10  k     d
 sy   10  an    a
```

emp with expenses  and shows emp's reporting level 1 and next higher supv2

now i want to get an outup by chaching each supervisor at level 1 and 2 and the corresponding exp. so that i get the supervisor's total span of control expenses

so after checking column Supv1 and Supv 2 the output to be

```
Sup  total.exp
d      31  
k      30
j      10
an     10
a      21
```

I have used multiple group_by and summarise then rbind the output . and then a final summarise to get the above output.  is there any apply() family function to do this in a simple way?

Comment: Since you have already tried something to solve this you can also include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(list(total.exp=rep(df$Exp, 2))
 , list(Sup=unlist(df[,c("Supv1","Supv2")])), sum)
#  Sup total.exp
#1   a        21
#2  an        10
#3   d        31
#4   j        10
#5   k        30
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the data in long format, group by Supervisor values and take `sum` of them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Supv')) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(Exp = sum(Exp))

#  value   Exp
#* <chr> <dbl>
#1 a        21
#2 an       10
#3 d        31
#4 j        10
#5 k        30
```

Comment: Thank you @ronak-shah  realised as a beginner at 44, need to learn more. cannot share what i worked on , would be embarrassing , it is too long :)